цикл прекращает выполнение при первом результате удовлетворяющем условие
Есть список из которого нужно добыть несколько частей ограниченных определенными словами. длина списка 101 элемент но на 65 перестает работать. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться!
wall_lst = []
len_lst = len (lst)
x = 0
while x < len_lst:
   if lst.index('designType:wsegment') <= x <= lst.index('type:design'):
        wall_lst.append (lst[x])
   x += 1


Какие индексы этих cтрок в списке? Зачем проверять индексы каждый раз? Один раз получите индексы, и выберите нужную часть списка через срез (slice)  lst[a:b+1]

Приведите пример данных, на которых возникает проблема.

несколько частей ограниченных определенными словами - пары ограничительных слов всегда одинаковые? Ваши срезы списков могут пересекаться? Каким образом происходит «перестает работать»? Он должен «перестать работать», а точнее после того как x превысит индекс второго значения дальнейшие итерации будут бессмысленны. Может второй индекс - 65? Если Вам надо найти несколько под списков, то тогда надо использовать изменение параметра start метода index.

… еще момент, что если мы ищем несколько подсписков и вынуждены применять метод index смещая стартовую позицию и пытаясь найти неопрделенное количество подсписков, то рано или поздно мы получим ValueError, это надо учитывать и обрабатывать.

@Alexey Trukhanov  все верно, так и происходит, второй интервал начинается с 74 индекса но до него дело не дошло. К примеру 65 не удовлетворяет заданному условию, но почему цикл не продолжается до 74 индекса. Я еще здесь не освоился и не знаю как добавить файл, чтоб было понятно о чем речь.

@MBo со срезом идея интересная, спасибо !

@AndreyRozumienko посмотрите мой ответ, ниже.

Так как пока от автора не получены ответы на заданные вопросы, буду телепатом. Представим, что автору надо найти все подсписки от одного определенного слова до другого, причем (возьмем простой случай) подсписки не пересекаются.
У автора в коде ищется только первое вхождение, после первого вхождения итерации проходят в холостую, очевидно, именно это автор называет "перестает работать". Чтобы алгоритм не переставал работать до конца списка, надо ввести в метод index параметр start, который указывает с какого индекса начинать поиск и как только мы нашли очередное вхождение, перемещать начало поиска на следующий элемент после последнего в найденном подсписке. Как только совпадений в списке не останется мы получим ValueError, обработаем его и выйдем из цикла.
Как-то так:
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z', 'f', 'g', 
       'a', 'i', 'j', 'z', 'l', 'm', 'n', 
       'a', 'p', 'g', 'z', 'd', 'g']
st = 0
out_lst = []
left_word = 'a'
right_word = 'z'

while True:
    try:
        out_lst.append(lst[lst.index(left_word , st):lst.index(right_word, st)+1])
    except ValueError:
        break
    st = lst.index(right_word, st) + 1


print(out_lst)

Получаем список подсписков.
